# Open chrome browser HTTP Post C#

Tags: c#, .net, google-chrome

My requirement is to open a chrome browser by submitting the form data using c# windows application. (HTTP Post Method). I have tried googling around but no luck. Anybody have any idea on how to do that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You want to manipulate chrome to go to a website and submit form data? Is that what you are asking? Something like starting chrome with arguments of the site and form data to submit?

Comment: I need to start a chrome with HTTP POST data.

Comment: Did you find the solution? I want to achieve a similar thing.

Answer (score -1):

You could do something like

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("chrome.exe", "http:\\www.anyurl.com");
```

or you could go with this approach
https://stackoverflow.com/a/1903456/3379750

Comment: How can we submit the data by using the above command? Above command just to start the chrome to that specific URL.