# From a WPF app how to open browser in *fullscreen* and send POST request to it

Tags: .net, wpf

My WPF application must open a browser window and post some values to it using HTTP POST.
And to make it even more complicated the browser must be in fullscreen.

I've managed to succeed with the first part by following this post: [How to open IE with post info in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1705201/how-to-open-ie-with-post-info-in-c?lq=1)
(embedding an invisible WebBrowser and then opening a new blank window from that).
However, I cannot make this browser window fullscreen.

One thing I tried was setting a registry value for IE to use fullscreen. However, this value is changed as soon as the user manually changes the size of the window.

Another thing I considered was to use Process.Start() to open a browser (IE) in kiosk mode. However, when using Process.Start() it is not possible to do a POST request.
A third thing I briefly considered was using javascript to do a fullscreen but I don't see this working together with a POST request.

I cannot make changes to the website that receives the POST.