# Opening web page on default Web browser and hiding URL parameters

Tags: vb.net, url, post, get, hide

I have an application that needs to open an external URL on the default Web Browser but I don't want to show the parameters on the URL so I think I need to make a POST instead of a GET, but how?

I'm using the following code to open an external default browser

```
Friend Sub WebOpen(ByVal WebAddress As String)
    Dim sInfo As New ProcessStartInfo(WebAddress)
    Process.Start(sInfo)
End Sub
```

But this expose all the parameters on the URL bar since make a GET not a POST.

---

**Solution:**
Make a temporary HTML file and open it using the previous code (WebOpen(ByVal WebAddress As String))

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<!-- <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> -->
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml">
<!--     <head>

    </head> -->
<body>
    <form name="Login" method="post" action="http://www.yourWebPage.com/" target="_self">
    <input id="accountLoginField" class="textInput" name="account" value="accountX" size="24"
        maxlength="32" type="hidden"/>
    <input id="userLoginField" class="textInput" name="user" value="userX" size="24"
        maxlength="32" type="hidden"/>
    <input class="textInput" name="password" value="PassX" size="24" maxlength="32" type="hidden"/>
    <input name="submit" value="Start Session" type="submit" id="btn" style="color: transparent;
        background-color: transparent; border-color: transparent; cursor: default;"/>
    <script type="text/javascript">
                <!--
        var counter = 0;
        var maxCount = 50;

        function pushSubmit() {
            if (counter++ < maxCount) {
                document.getElementById('btn').click();
            }
        }
        //start the process
        window.setTimeout(pushSubmit(), 30);              
    </script>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The answer you are looking for is on this page:


  [StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1705201/how-to-open-ie-with-post-info-in-c)

Comment: Ok, thanks for the info, now I have an HTML file with a button and it works Ok. There's any way to make that button autoclick when the HTML file gets open?

Comment: Button in a HTML file or the windows form?

Comment: In HTML, but I'm solved reading some other post in this forum, plus I make and invisible button too. Should do I add the code(solution) to the original post?

Comment: Yes, that would be helpful to others and if you can mark my post as an answer, that would be terrific. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could use a string encryptor in vb.net (you'll have to find that yourself) and then do this:

```
Process.Start(Decrypt("encryptedstringhere"))
```

That will 'hide' the parameters from anyone trying to decompile your code.
OR
Once you have compiled your executable, find a vb.net obfuscation program (just google it) and obfuscate your exe. This will make it unreadable to nayone who attempts to decompile it or find what string is in your parameters....

Comment: I'm not trying to obfuscate my code, I just want to open a web page in the default Web Browser hiding the parameters to log in to the Web Page from the user; that's why I need to make a POST instead of a GET. But thanks I will have this in mind just in case that I need to.